# Migrate Application .Net 1.1 to .Net 4.0

Tags: .net

i have created application in .Net 1.1 32 bit so now i have to convert my application in 64 bit so i m migrate my application to .Net 4.0
bcoz of my application working with good with 32 bit server. but problem with 64 bit server and problem is i have used connectivity with sap into my application
it was connect succesfully with 32 bit but sap connector not work with 64 bit.

any step is keep safe while migrate application 1.1 to 4.0  ?

Answer (score 0):

hopefully I understand the issue correctly. Your SAP connectivity probably relies on a 32-bit ActiveX or similar SDK object in order to talk to SAP. Now that you've switched to 64-bit that SDK object will no longer be accessible.

First thing to check is whether SAP provides a 64-bit version of their SDK. If all else fails you'll need to create a secondard application that runs in 32-bit mode and does the talking to SAP which you can then call from your 64-bit app.

Hope I understand the issue correctly.